# How to Bind two datable in a grid view

Tags: asp.net

```
DataTable dt = try.Query(" select Rooms.RoomId, Rooms.RoomType From Rooms INNER JOIN Reservations ON ( Rooms.RoomId = Reservations.RoomId ) AND GETDATE() BETWEEN Reservations.CheckInDate AND Reservations.CheckOutDate ORDER BY Rooms.RoomType");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            LblMessage.Text = " No Room Available";
        }
        else 
        {
            DataTable dt1 = try.Query( "Select  Rooms.RoomType, Rooms.PricePerNight From Rooms INNER JOIN Reservations ON (Rooms.RoomId != Reservations.Roomid) ORDER BY Rooms.Roomtype");

        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridResult.DataSource = dt1;
            GridResult.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            LblMessage.Text = "No Rooms Availble";
        }
```

When i search i don't get any available rooms "No Rooms Availble" is what will come up, I have so many rooms available
My intention is  for user on search it will run through the datatable reservations, reservations.roomid compare it with the table Rooms rooms.roomid them show results of those items that are not find in the reservations but are in the rooms table to the Grid View..
thats all

thanks please help me out

Comment: The problem can be on the SQL statements. Did you run them against your database on the manager tool?

Comment: please give some more details about your problem..

Answer (score 2):

I think the first condition is wrong. The code should be

```
DataTable dt = try.Query("YOUR QUERY");
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
   // Grid Bind Code
}
else {
   LblMessage.Text = " No Room Available";
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: I must be blind. Didn't notice that. Damn Fridays. LOL

Comment: Thanks i have tried it but it did not work.. what have in mind is for user on search it will run through the datable reservations, compare it with the table Rooms them show results of those items that are not find in the reservations but are in the rooms table to the Grid View.. Please help me out

Comment: @user1736648, i guess all the rooms exist in the ReservationTable because each room must be reserved sometime. So the problem is exist in the where condition, as you can see you didn't specify the date between criteria in second query. Try that and hopefully you will get rid out of this. :)